# jquery.fn not works on server, it works on local

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote below function in javascript file.
Previously, below function works on my server and local, but today it works on my local only. Suddenly it stops working on server. i checked the code there is no any change. I don't understand why this happens.?

```
jQuery.fn.guideWidget = function(e) {
    alert("guideWdget");
},
jQuery.fn.loading = function() {
    this.prepend("<div class='fnLoading' style='height:" + this.height() + "px;width:" + this.width() + "px'><div class='ajaxOverlayInvis' style='display:block'></div><div class='ajaxOverlay' style='display:block;position:absolute'><div class='loadingimage' style='display:block'></div></div></div>")
}, 
jQuery.fn.loadingDone = function() {
    this.find("div.fnLoading").first().remove()
}
```

Is there any alternate way to write above function?
What am i doing wrong in above function please suggest me.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you trying with? What is `e` parameter at function?

Comment: try to provide cdn for jQuery's library in case you are not.

Comment: @guest271314 version: 2.2.0

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi cdn ??? i dont understand it?

Comment: can u post your whole code

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi now code updated. all this type of fuction in js file. on local every function executes properly, and on server it does not works

Comment: how are you loading Jquery.js. Locally or through cdn.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi locally

Comment: try replacing your script with this:`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also check your console for errors.

Comment: there is no any error in console

Comment: did you replace the `<script src="">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141859/discussion-between-sachin-bahukhandi-and-harish-mahajan).

Comment: yes, i replace it. still not works